# Program to upgrade configuration files

Tags: shell, diff, merge

When upgrading Ubuntu (and probably other *nixes), the upgrade process will show a diff of changed configuration files and ask whether I'd like to replace them, keep the old version, or manually merge them. I couldn't find any such programs with Google or searching through the [Ubuntu packaging](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete) documentation. Do you know of any such programs which have the following features?

- Few or no dependencies (ideally a single shell script).
- Shell only (ideally without curses).
- Does *not* try to be "clever," for example by automatically merging.

Edit: I've written this small thing to do some preliminary checks and ask the user what to do, but it's not very flexible or nice:

```
for path
do
    if [ ! -e "${path}.new" ]
    then
        # No new revision; skip
        continue
    fi

    if [[ $(diff "${path}"{,.new} | grep '^[<>]' | grep -v '^[<>][[:space:]]*\(#\|START=\)' | wc -l) -eq 0 ]]
    then
        # No interesting lines; skip
        continue
    fi

    clear
    diff -u "${path}"{,.new}

    unset action
    while [[ ! "${action-}" =~ ^[sr]$ ]]
    do
        echo "Do you want to replace $path with ${path}.new?"
        read -s -n 1 -p $'[s]kip, [r]eplace: \n' action
    done

    case "$action" in
        s)
            continue
            ;;
        r)
            cp -v "${path}"{,.new}
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Invalid action ${action}!"
            exit 2
    esac
done
```

Comment: Just for clarification: which system are you on? Ubuntu?

Comment: @phunehehe: Linux from Scratch and Ubuntu.

Comment: I'd much rather leverage version control. In fact, I wish Debian packages systematically checked the upstream versions into a branch and let me set up a merge policy. [Etckeeper](http://joey.kitenet.net/code/etckeeper/) goes part of the way with version control for `/etc`, but it doesn't record upstream versions, which means you can't go merges.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect the program you've seen is [`dpkg`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dpkg) the low-level of package management in Debian-ish distributions (using `apt(itude)`).  [see here for a blog post explaining its configuration file management](http://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/09/21/debian-conffile-configuration-file-managed-by-dpkg/).

You could probably hijack this function, i.e., [create your own `.deb` packages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29) - which, I suspect, might be pretty much hassle for what you're trying to achieve.

There's another way to go, you could have a look at [NetBSD's `etcupdate` tool](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/guide/en/chap-updating.html#updating-etcupdate) (while it's rather NetBSD-specific, you might find [its source (shell script)](http://cvsweb.netbsd.se/cgi-bin/bsdweb.cgi/src/usr.sbin/etcupdate/etcupdate?rev=1.50;content-type=text%2Fx-cvsweb-markup) interesting nonetheless).  Apparently, [Gentoo has an `etc-update`, too](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-amd64.xml?part=3&chap=4#doc_chap2), but I could find neither sources nor more information (the link also mentions `dispatch-conf`, could be interesting, too; I don't know.)

Comment: `etc-update` is a bash script, and I have [uploaded](http://pastebin.com/ALD61R4s) the copy on my machine.